# Assign each value using different loops in python

Tags: python, django, loops, foreach

Hi I got a loop where I get different parameters (age, date, role, etc.), and I got an array where I get these values. How can I assign each value to eache parameter. I'll add some code below

I tried this but obviosly didn't work

```
parameters = Parametros.objects.filter(job_id=job.id)
        if request.method == 'POST':    
            for parameter in parameters:
                #Update parameters
                params = request.POST.getlist('parameter')
                for i in range(len(params)):
                    cursor.execute("UPDATE Jobs_parametros SET parameter_value='" + params[i] + "' WHERE parameter_name='" + parameter.parameter_name + "' AND job_id=" + str(job.id))
```

Here we can see "parameters" where I'm assigning parameter.parameter.name for the different names. After that we can see the array where I get the values called "params". I want to assign each value I get from params to the name of the parameter to execute the code showed in the last line

The result that I got with the code showed is each parameter name with the last value I added. The values are updated but only take the last value in my form and didn't assigned my values like the date and age for eache parameter name

[image]

Comment: Previous iteration of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75225084/assign-each-value-in-a-loop-in-python

Comment: Hi @Matthias I obviously did that, but I didn't show it in my code beacuse it's not relevant for my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems nobody could resolve my question, instead answered woth useless answers so here is how i could resolve it

```
parameters = Parametros.objects.filter(job_id=job.id)
        aux = 0
        if request.method == 'POST':    
            for parameter in parameters:
                #update parameters
                aux = aux + 1
                values = request.POST.getlist('parameter')
                for i in range(len(values)):
                    if (i + 1) == aux:
                        cursor.execute("UPDATE Jobs_parametros SET parameter_value='" + values[i] + "' WHERE parameter_name='" + parameter.parameter_name + "' AND job_id='" + str(job.id) + "'")
```

I used an aux to match index numbers for each array. It was simple logic